# Custom atomic UPDATE commands inside SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, dapper, savechanges

For various reasons I need to be able to do several custom SQL `UPDATE` commands when I call `SaveChanges` on a `DbContext`. I want this to happen atomically so either both the regular `SaveChanges` and the SQL succeeds, or neither does.

I don't know how to accomplish this though. What I've tried so far is this and various variations:

[EF transactions — Gist](https://gist.github.com/4004127)

The error here is (on the `ExecuteSqlCommand` call):

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.

Okay, fair enough. The `ExecuteSqlCommand` doesn't have an overload that accepts a transaction though. So, I installed the Dapper package and replaced the offending line with this Dapper call and I pass in the transaction:

```
this.Database.Connection
  .Execute("insert into Tests (Foo, Bar) values ('test', 2)", 
  transaction: tran);
```

but now the error happens on `base.SaveChanges()` and it gives me the following:

> SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.

So apparently `SaveChanges` always creates a new transaction even though I created one on the connection of the datacontext already?

Is there any way in which I can accomplish what I want?

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 Code First.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap a `TransactionScope` around all operations. This class is the common abstraction for .NET transactions. EF and `SqlConnection`'s will enlist automatically. Be sure to look for best-practices though as there are some pitfalls like accidentally triggering distributed transactions.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my worry as I've triggered MSDTC in the past and kind of shied away from the whole thing I guess. I hadn't even given it a try yet as I thought it would create two transactions, rather than one. Apparently my understanding of `TransactionScope` is off :) I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JulianR think of it as an investment in your skillset :) Anyway, the trick is to never use more than one (open) SqlConnection. As EF is stupid about this you probably need to call `ObjectContext db; db.Connection.Open()` before you enter the `TransactionScope`. Write yourself some unit tests to confirm. Turn off MSDTC to make the tests able to fail.